# I'm stuck on lasso mode

Tags: edit-mode

I started using Blender yesterday after using Maya for 6 years. I'm in edit mode, stuck on some kind of lasso mode. I'm not sure how I even got into lasso mode. Previously it was in circle mode. This is only happening in Edit mode. In object mode I have a traditional marque square to select with. I would like to get this in Edit mode. Please can anyone tell me how to get rid of this lasso? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The hotkey W lets you swap between selection modes. Press W a few times until you get to your desired selection mode.

Comment: I tried the W, it didn't do anything. I feel like there are lot of bugs in Blender. But, I finally did figure it out. I was trying to right click. It never occurred to me I needed to left click to change it, lol. This is so different than Maya, lol.

Comment: The shortcut might be different depending your settings. You can see it in the tooltip when hovering the GUI with your mouse. But in any case you can just hold-click that active tool (or any active tool icon with a white corner) to see and select a different mode of the tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you click and hold the lasso tool in edit mode, you will get a list of tools to select from:[image]

From there you can select "Select Box". You can also do this in object mode.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I finally got it. I was right clicking instead of left clicking. This is such a learning process, lol. I'm just coming over from Maya. It's all so different. thanks again.

Comment: @akabk_74 I think you can change the default to right-click instead of left click to select